Predicate Logic: Prove ¬∃x.p(x), given 1. ∀x.(p(x) ⟹ ¬q(x)) 2. ∃x.p(x) ⟹ ∀x.q(x)
I'm having trouble solving:
Prove ¬∃x.p(x), given 1. ∀x.(p(x) ⟹ ¬q(x)) 2. ∃x.p(x) ⟹ ∀x.q(x)
I think I need to get $\exists x.p(x) \Rightarrow \neg (\forall x.q(x))$  to then use negation introduction, but I'm struggling with creating the implication.
What should I do next? Is there better way to do  it using fitch style proof? Thanks in advance.
1. AX:(p(X) => ~q(X))      Premise
2. EX:p(X) => AX:q(X)      Premise
| 3. EX:p(X)               Assumption
| 4. AX:q(X)               Implication elimination: 2, 3
| | 5. AX:q(X)             Assumption
| | 6. q(c)                Universal Elimination: 5
| | | 7. p(c)              Assumption
| | | 8. p(c) => ~q(c)     Universal Elimination: 1
| | | 9. ~q(c)             Implication elimination: 8,9
| | 10. p(c) => ~q(c)      Implication introduction: 7,9
| | | 11. p(c)             Assumption
| | | 12. q(c)             Reiteration: 6
| | 13. p(c) => q(c)       Implication introduction: 11,12
| | 14. ~p(c)              Negation Introduction: 10,13
| 15. AX:q(X) => ~p(c)     Implication introdcution:5,14
(how to I get AX:q(x) => p(c), to then use negation introduction?)


@MauroALLEGRANZA Could you please elaborate further? How to apply Existential Elimination to 3? We would need to have for example AX:(p(X) => ~AX:q(X)), since we can't use it directly on AX:(p(X) => ~q(X)) having EX:p(X). What am I missing? And how do i get ¬q(c)?

See Existential Elimination: From ∃xp(x) start a sub-proof assuming p(c) with c new. Then use c with 1 and 4 to get respectively p(c) ⟹ ¬q(c) and q(c) and then the contradiction $\bot$. Now you can close the sub-proof discharging the tenporary assumption p(c) and retaining the conclusion $\bot$.

@MauroALLEGRANZA Ohhh, now I see! I can't express how grateful i am. Thank you!

Hint
You have to use Modus Ponens to derive  $∀xq(x)$ from 3 and 2 and then apply Existential Elimination to 3 assuming $p(c)$ (for $c$ new). Then $q(c)$ and $p(c) ⟹ ¬q(c)$.
Having the contradiction: $q(c)$ and $¬q(c)$ you can conclude with $¬∃xp(x)$ using Negation Introduction.
See the "specification" for the Existential Elimination rule: from the formula $∃xp(x)$ you have to start a sub-proof assuming $p(c)$ with $c$ new. When you derive the contradiction $\bot$, it has no occurrences of $c$ and thus the proviso of the rule has been satisfied and you can close the sub-proof discharging the temporary assumption $p(c)$, nd retaining the conclusion ⊥
.
